# Strange behavior when modifying an array of Objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I initialize like so:

```js
const balances = Array(5).fill({})
```

Later, I modify the balance for the first object using:

```js
balances[0]['USD'] = 1000
```

I expect this to change only the balance for the first index. Instead, the 'USD' key is set for all of the elements:

```js
balances // [{USD: 1000}, {USD: 1000}, {USD: 1000}, {USD: 1000}, {USD: 1000}]

// when I expected this:
balances // [{USD: 1000}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: `fill` uses the same exact value for every slot in the array. So a reference to the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `fill`ing the array with the same object. (We can see this by using the [`===` strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).)

```
> balances = Array(5).fill({})
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
> balances[0] === balances[1]
true
```

You'll need to construct an object for each slot - an FP (if not necessarily pretty or efficient) way to do this would be

```
> balances = Array(5).fill(null).map(() => ({}))
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
> balances[0] === balances[1]
false
```

A non-FP, old-school, imperative *but* plenty fast (79% faster than the one above, by one quick benchmark) way is simply

```
var balances = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) balances.push({});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a mapping function to fill the array with different objects.

```
const balances = Array.from({length: 5}, _=>({}));
```